# Is there a way for me to throw an exception without it printing the stack trace?

Tags: java

The goal is to be able to do:

```
throw new RuntimeException();
```

without it printing:

```
Exception in thread "main" java.util.RuntimeException
at grame.GrameManager.add(GrameManager.java:40)
at grame.GrameManager.add(GrameManager.java:47)
at grame.Entity.<init>(Entity.java:56)
at grame.Entity.<init>(Entity.java:28)
at test.Test.main(Test.java:20)
```

(for example).

Is this possible? If so, how would I go about doing this?

Comment: why do you want to do this? this is generally not a good thing to do

Comment: I should probably elaborate my intentions. I'm making an exception catcher which displays the problem in a neat GUI and even lets the user email the log. The thing is, sometimes the program that caused the exception will keep running because essentially, when I called on my "exception manager", it caught and ignored the exception. I guess my question is: Is there any way to stop a program (just like throwing an exception would) without terminating it (and making it all invisible, as in no console prints)?

Answer (score 4, accepted):

Since exceptions are important, you could use a logging mechanism like log4j (http://logging.apache.org/log4j/1.2/) and set the logging to a different level when you don't want some exceptions to be printed or log to a file instead of console for example.

If you just don't care about the exception, catch it and do nothing with it (empty catch, which is awful).

Answer (score 3):

You can redirect System.err by setting `System.setErr(null);`

Answer (score 3):

No thrown exception ever directly generates a stacktrace to the error console.  It's up to the code who is calling it to do so.  In the case of a main program:

```
public static void main(String args[]) throws Exception {
   // do something that throws an exception
}
```

If you don't catch the exception, the system will actually spit it out to the console i believe.

Somewhere along the way, you need to deal with the exception.  If showing it in the GUI is what you want, then you'll have to do something like this:

```
public interface ExceptionHandler {
     void handleException(Exception e);
}


public static void main(String args[]) {
  ExceptionHandler exceptionHandler = ...;

  try {
     // something that might throw an exception
  }
  catch (Exception e) {
     exceptionHandler.handle(e);
  }
}
```

Answer (score 2):

Just catch the exception, and don't put anything in the catch block.

I should add that doing this is generally a bad idea. Having that stack trace, or some sort of message is very useful when finding out what went wrong in your program.

Comment: Yeah I know. I ask because I'm making a (quite awesome) exception catcher (with a GUI and a built in emailer). Sometimes though I'd like to stop the program so the catcher can run and that's when I throw exceptions (which I'd like to hide).

Answer (score 1):

All that you really need to do is catch it...   However, this is a really bad idea. You may want to make your own exception and catch that. This way you will not swallow exceptions that you should not be ignoring. The only time that you should really consider to do this, is if you cannot allow your application to blow up. If that is the case then you should at the very least log the error.

[This](http://docs.oracle.com/javase/tutorial/essential/exceptions/runtime.html) explains it better than I can (and is a good resource regardless). Basically, it suggests that:

> "If a client can reasonably be expected to recover from an exception,
>   make it a 
>       checked exception. If a client cannot do anything to recover from the exception, 
>       make it an unchecked exception".

Answer (score 1):

If you want the method to kill the program without printing a stack trace, place it in a try/catch block, and under catch simply use the statement:

```
System.exit(1)
```

This lets the system know that the program exited with an irregular (non-zero) state, but does not print anything to System.err.

Answer (score 0):

Like this:

```
try {
    some code...
} catch (RuntimeException e) {

  }
```

Comment: You really should not do this

Comment: Why should I really not do this?

Comment: Runtime exceptions are (should) only be thrown when there is a bug in your code (class cast, nullpointer, etc). these are not things that should be swallowed. You should just fix your code so that these issues do not arise. The only time that you should do this is if you cannot allow your application to blow up, but definitely not as the general case.

Answer (score 0):

**1.** `Java compiler` **only cares during compilation that you have given a catch for a try**, whether you **implement any code in the catch or not.**

**2.** You can keep the catch block **empty**, or **print it on the console**, **log it..etc....**

**eg:**

```
try{

    }catch(Exception ex){



  }
```

**3.** But `printStackTrace()` prints the `method name`, `class name` , `file name` and the `line number` **where the exception has occurred.**